# MPICC with different versions of GCC

Tags: compiling, gcc, mpi

I need to use `MPICH` with different versions of `GCC`.

Is it possible to change GCC without having to recompile MPI?

---

#### Example

I'd like to do something like this:

```
mpicc --compiler=/usr/bin/gcc-5
```

---

Is it possible? Different versions of `GCC` are enough, I don't need to use `icc` or any other compiler.

Comment: Not sure about MPICH, but for OpenMPI this has been answered in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3353119/how-to-force-openmpi-to-use-gcc-instead-of-icc-is-recompiling-openmpi-necessary). *TLDR*: `export OMPI_CC=gcc-5` before compiling  with `mpicc`.